# Is there Maven analog of Ant's <jar> task?

Tags: java, maven, ant

Need to jar a particular dir and place it to specified folder. Previously it was performed by ant's task:

```
<jar destfile="${dir}/mainlib.jar" basedir="${lib}" excludes="**/*.java" />
```

Is there an analog for maven?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use jar plugin, see: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/ and http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the `jar` goal of the `maven-jar-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html), by binding an execution with custom configuration to the `package` phase.

Alternatively, you could just use the maven-antrun-plugin to run arbitrary Ant commands in your Maven build.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like jar plugin is exactly what i am looking for.